# IOS: With tableview, how to access data object from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a Master-Detail tableview and would like take the user to a different Detail VC depending on properties of the object being displayed.

For example, if an actor is in a movie, I'd like to go to a movie View Controller, but if the actor is in a TV show, a view controller optimized for a TV show.

I have wired the detail VCs to the view controller, not the table view so that using didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I can send the user to different detail VCs using logic and performSegue.

However, the information needed to implement the logic is in the data object in cellforrowatindexpath.  So my question is how can pass this info to didSelectRow or alternatively place the logic for the segue in cellforrowatindexpath.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is my current code:

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *theCellClicked = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *segueName = nil;

    if ([_credit.type  isEqual: @"movie"]) {

            segueName = @"goToMovie";
        }
         else if ([_credit.type isEqual: @"television"]) {
            segueName = @"goToTVShow";
        }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: segueName sender: self];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
    Credit *credit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
       cell.textLabel.text = credit.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fetched results controller will still be in scope inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.  So you can:

```
Credit *credit = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([credit.type  isEqual: @"movie"]) {
   segueName = @"goToMovie";
}
else if ([credit.type isEqual: @"television"]) {
   segueName = @"goToTVShow";
}
```